# SQL Conditional Summing

Tags: sql, ms-access-2010, calculated-columns

Im trying to code a calculation in Access that involves the SUM of some values plus the result of an IF statement.

Here is a table of the kind of data I'm dealing with (from 'CostBaseQuery)

```
CompanyName Year    AssetName  DatapointID  Datapointname                DatapointValue
CompanyA    2011    AssetA     4025         Active operated wells           129
CompanyA    2011    AssetA     4058         API gravity of oil              38.5563255
CompanyA    2011    AssetA     4032         Number of gas lift wells        70
CompanyA    2011    AssetA     4033         Number of wells with ESPs       0
CompanyA    2011    AssetA     4036         Wells with CO2 production       25
CompanyA    2011    AssetA     4035         Wells with H2S production       9
CompanyA    2011    AssetA     4038         Wells with high pressure        0
CompanyA    2011    AssetA     4037         Wells with high temperature     0
CompanyA    2011    AssetA     4034         Wells with scale production     42
CompanyA    2011    AssetA     4039         Wells with wax                  0
```

The calculation needs to **SUM(DatapointValue)** WHERE DatapointID IN (4032,4033,4035,4036,4037,4038,4039)

**PLUS the value returned from the IF Statement**

IF (API gravity of oil <=5 or >20, Use the value of ActiveOperatedWells, Else 0)

I tried to use the following method to code the calculation but it outputs data on each iteration of the SUM rather than carrying out the SUM calculation and THEN the IF statement.

```
SELECT qb1.CompanyName, qb1.AssetName, qb1.Year, 
(SUM(qb1.DatapointValue) 
+ IIF(qb2.DatapointValue>=5, 
       IIF(qb2.DatapointValue<20, qb3.DatapointValue, 0), 0)) 
AS NumberOfWellCompletions

FROM (CostBaseQuery AS qb1 
     INNER JOIN CostBaseQuery AS qb2 
          ON qb1.CompanyYearAssetID=qb2.CompanyYearAssetID) 
     INNER JOIN CostBaseQuery AS qb3 
          ON qb1.CompanyYearAssetID=qb3.CompanyYearAssetID

WHERE qb1.DatapointID IN (4032,4033,3036,4035,4038,4037,4034,4039)
AND qb2.DatapointID=4058 AND qb3.DatapointID=4025

GROUP BY qb1.CompanyName, qb1.AssetName, qb1.Year, 
qb1.DatapointValue, qb2.DatapointValue, qb3.DatapointValue
```

Any help would be much appreciated and I hope this makes more sense than my previous rambling!

Comment: However, it is still building an application one highly-localized question at a time.

Comment: Im trying to transfer 200+ calculations out of an Excel model into an Access model and my SQL skills aren't amazing hence the odd question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SUM(qb1.DatapointValue + IIF(ab2.DatapointValue <=5 AND qb2.DatapointValue > 20, qb3.DatapointValue, 0)) as NumberOfWellCompletions
...

GROUP BY qb1.CompanyName, qb1.AssetName, qb1.Year
```

You can simplify your SUM (well, not clear about what you want to sum, but you may have a problem of brackets)

You must be clear if you need to check `<= 5` or `>=5` (difference between text and code in your question)

You must change your GROUP BY

Comment: Thanks for that, i have simplified my IF statement but the GROUP BY edit causes an aggregation error

Comment: @Magda Well if you copy the first part of code (SUM), the GROUP BY problem should also disapear (you seem to have a problem of brackets with your SUM). Or maybe remove just qb1.DatapointValue in the GROUP BY

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you want to group by `DatapointValue`, since these are the individual values, and you are looking for the sum.

Try changing the `GROUP BY` to:

```
GROUP BY qb1.CompanyName, qb1.AssetName, qb1.Year
```

Comment: I tried that initially but i got an error that i 'tried to execute a query that does not include [my calculation] as part of an aggregate function'